# Video not working properly after switching with a TESmart 4 port KVM switch

Tags: drivers, gpu-driver

I just bought a TESmart 4 port KVM switch model HKS0401A1U that supports EDID. I have an Dell XPS with Ubuntu 21.10, RasperyPi also with Ubuntu 21.10 and a HP with windows (and a DVI to HDMI adapter). Both Ubuntu are currently driving my Dell 27" monitor at 4K and the windows in only doing HD.

When switching to the rasberypi and windows computer the video works fine but when switching to the Dell Ubuntu system the video just shows white noise. The dell is using built in Intel graphics (I believe but there is also an external Nvidia GeForce GTX 1650 Mobile / Max-Q as well but I'm not sure how to find which is being used).

Is there any ideas on how to fix this? (for reference this same computer was having an issue before 21.10 where the whole computer would crash if the video was unplugged while on but that has now stopped)

Comment: Nvidia X Server Settings should tell you which one is in use IF you have Nvidia drivers installed.

Comment: I don't have the propitiatory nividia drivers installed

Comment: Then maybe you should?